# iOS: Can I detect the user located country?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can I detect whether a user moved to another country? 
(Not using `Locale.current`)
The location detection should be running in background.

I'm hoping to do something like this.

Eg. A user from US leaves the country to UK. Then, when the user reach UK, i am able to detect it at the background and send notification.

Comment: Are you using CLLocationManager ?

Comment: @Pushkraj I've never used it before but i read through the documentation, CLLocationManager can only possible to return a defined radius. Can I use it to detect a country?

Comment: Using current location, you can get country as well. But problem is that CLLocationManager will not work when app is in background or terminated.

Comment: @Pushkraj Is there any possible ways to run location service in background ?

Comment: @hatched Did you get the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You should in your `Info.plist`, set  `allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates` to YES, this you can search google, and lots of answer for adapt iOS 9.

First you can use `CLLocationManager` to get the location:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad  
{  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib .  
    //delegate  
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;  
    //The desired location accuracy.  
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;  
    //Specifies the minimum update distance in meters.  

    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;  

    self.locationManager.purpose = @"To provide functionality based on user's current location.";  

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  
} 

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{  
UIAlertView* av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"update" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"didUpdateToLocation:  newLocation: %@  old:%@",newLocation,oldLocation] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil nil];  
   [av show];  

}
```

Secondly, you can use  `CLGeocoder` to get country or city.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation  
{  
// get city name  
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];   
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error)  
{  
    if (array.count > 0)  
    {  
        CLPlacemark *placemark = [array objectAtIndex:0];  
        NSString *city = placemark.locality;  
    }  
    else if (error == nil && [array count] == 0)  
    {  
        NSLog(@"No results were returned.");  
    }  
    else if (error != nil)  
    {  
        NSLog(@"An error occurred = %@", error);  
    }  
    }];  
}
```

You can give a duration to get location per duration:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{  
newLocation = [locations lastObject];  
double lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;  
double lon = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;  
NSLog(@"lat:%f,lon:%f",lat,lon);  


    if (!self.deferringUpdates) {  
        CLLocationDistance distance = 500;  
        NSTimeInterval time = 20;  
        [locationManager allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled:distance  
                                                       timeout:time];  
        self.deferringUpdates = YES;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why are you using release for alert, we are using ARC nowdays.

Comment: And this code will not work when app is terminated. He wants something which will notify when user changes location even if app is in background or terminated state.

Answer (score 1):

You can create [`UNNotificationRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest) with exit [`UNLocationNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unlocationnotificationtrigger).

### UNNotificationRequest

> A UNNotificationRequest object is used to schedule a local notification and manages the content for a delivered notification. A notification request object contains a UNNotificationContent object with the contents of the notification. It also contains the UNNotificationTrigger object that specifies the conditions that trigger the delivery of the notification. For a delivered notification, you use these objects to fetch information about the notification.

### UNLocationNotificationTrigger

> A UNLocationNotificationTrigger object causes the delivery of a notification when the device enters or leaves a specified geographic region. Use this object to specify the region information needed to trigger the notification. Location triggers can fire once or they can fire multiple times.
>
> Apps must request access to location services and must have when-in-use permissions to use this class. To request permission to use location services, call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method of CLLocationManager before scheduling any location-based triggers.

#### Flow

Each time user opens app, check his local country and define location trigger

```
let region: CLRegion = <your code defining country region>
region.notifyOnEntry = false
region.notifyOnExit = true
let trigger = UNLocationNotificationTrigger(region: region, repeats: false)
```

and using that trigger reschedule notification request (UNNotificationRequest).

When trigger fires (user leaves region) — app will present local notification, and if user taps on it, app starts, and if you add handler on local notification open you can notify your server about user moving away and check his new country and do what you need to do.

Comment: what should be in "region" country code ?

Comment: @ekta-padaliya, oh, it should be an instance of [`CLRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clregion) (or of its subclasess).